# How does recursion work while defining multidimensional template arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays

This is the code I found online.

```
template<class T, unsigned ... RestD> struct array;

template<class T, unsigned PrimaryD >
struct array<T, PrimaryD>
{
typedef T type[PrimaryD];
type data;
T& operator[](unsigned i) { return data[i]; }

};

template<class T, unsigned PrimaryD, unsigned ... RestD >
struct array<T, PrimaryD, RestD...>
{
typedef typename array<T, RestD...>::type OneDimensionDownArrayT;
typedef OneDimensionDownArrayT type[PrimaryD];
type data;
OneDimensionDownArrayT& operator[](unsigned i) { return data[i]; }
};

int main()
{
array<int, 2, 3>::type a4 = { { 1, 2, 3}, { 1, 2, 3} };
array<int, 2, 3> a5{ { { 1, 2, 3}, { 4, 5, 6} } };
std::cout << a5[1][2] << std::endl;

array<int, 3> a6{ {1, 2, 3} };
std::cout << a6[1] << std::endl;

array<int, 1, 2, 3> a7{ { { { 1, 2, 3}, { 4, 5, 6 } } }};
std::cout << a7[0][1][2] << std::endl;
}
```

Could you explain what this code does exactly? I understand that recursion is used in some form here to create a multidimensional array, but I am a little confused on how this process works.

I am also confused about this line:

```
array<int, 2, 3>::type a4 = { { 1, 2, 3}, { 1, 2, 3} };
```

What is the ::type?

Answer (score 0):

This is whats called template specialization.

The first thing you must know is that anything defined with `template` is evaluated at compile time.

Looking at your code, there are two main cases we want to consider:

1. When the array is of one-dimension
2. When the array has more than one dimension

The following describes the one-dimensional case:

```
template<class T, unsigned PrimaryD >
struct array<T, PrimaryD>
{
typedef T type[PrimaryD];
type data;
T& operator[](unsigned i) { return data[i]; }

};
```

As you can see the above struct is specialized to only accept two template parameters, the first one is `T` the data type of the array, and the second is `PrimaryD` which simply means how long should the array be.

Now for the 2nd specialization:

```
template<class T, unsigned PrimaryD, unsigned ... RestD >
struct array<T, PrimaryD, RestD...>
{
    // if the template contains array<int, 1, 2, 3, 4>
    // then RestD... will unpack the values   2, 3, 4
    typedef typename array<T, RestD...>::type 
    OneDimensionDownArrayT;
   
    typedef OneDimensionDownArrayT type[PrimaryD];
    type data;
    
    // This will return an array type 
    // you can keep on making a call to operator[] until the type of the OneDimensionDownArrayT refers to the previous specialization
    OneDimensionDownArrayT& operator[](unsigned i) { return 
              data[i]; 
    }
};
```

Now for your example:

`array<int, 2, 3>::type a4 = { { 1, 2, 3}, { 1, 2, 3} }`

What the compiler will do is sort of match the template parameters namely, `int`, `2`, and `3` which evaluate to the 2nd specialization.

Let's follow it through:

`array<int, 2, 3>` which is a struct contains the following concrete types:
OneDimensionalT which is equal to array<int, 3>
and an operator[] function that returns an array<int, 3>.

OneDimensionalT is equal to array<int, 3> because if you unpack the `RestD...` values you will only get `3`, the `2` is already consumed by the first template parameter, `PrimaryD`.

Adding a 3rd dimension follows the same logic, keep on defining smaller dimension struct array types recursively using only the n-1 dimension values of the parameter pack `RestD...`

Oh and btw, the line on the top is just to declare the base type so we can specialize it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! An extremely concise explanation of the problem I have been struggling with long, thank you so much!